# activerecord 3.2.13 query to use where with not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I know there is Model.where.not for newer versions of activerecord. Is there a workaround for older version of activerecord?

I want to do something like `Model.where.not(:completed_at => nil)`

where `completed_at` is a timestamp value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arel but it's a bit verbose

```
Model.where(Model.arel_table[:completed_at].not_eq(nil))
```

Otherwise go for the raw SQL

```
Model.where('completed_at IS NOT NULL')
```